# C# / WPF Color to Double Conversion

Tags: c#, wpf, colors

I am attempting to create a WPF program (for practice) that will allow the selection of a color based on three slider bars (red, green, and blue), save (apply) said color based on the rgb values from the slider, to a sample box and a save for later box.

My Problem: I can't figure out how to convert the saved color from the save for later box back into values that can be placed back into the slider values. I can apply the saved color, but it's the values of the saved color that I want. This code compiles and runs until I click and initiate Click_savedColor, then the program freezes.

WPF Code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10">
            <Label DockPanel.Dock="Left" FontWeight="Bold">R:</Label>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=slColorR, Path=Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DockPanel.Dock="Right" TextAlignment="Right" Width="40" />
            <Slider Name="slColorR" Maximum="255" TickPlacement="BottomRight" TickFrequency="1" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" ValueChanged="ColorSlider_ValueChanged" />
        </DockPanel>

        <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10">
            <Label DockPanel.Dock="Left" FontWeight="Bold">G:</Label>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=slColorG, Path=Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DockPanel.Dock="Right" TextAlignment="Right" Width="40" />
            <Slider Name="slColorG" Maximum="255" TickPlacement="BottomRight" TickFrequency="1" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" ValueChanged="ColorSlider_ValueChanged" />
        </DockPanel>

        <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10">
            <Label DockPanel.Dock="Left" FontWeight="Bold">B:</Label>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=slColorB, Path=Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DockPanel.Dock="Right" TextAlignment="Right" Width="40" />
            <Slider Name="slColorB" Maximum="255" TickPlacement="BottomRight" TickFrequency="1" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" ValueChanged="ColorSlider_ValueChanged" />
        </DockPanel>
    </StackPanel>
    <GridSplitter Name="test" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <Button Name="compColor" Grid.Column="2" Click="Click_compColor"/>
    <GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
    <Button Name="savedColor" Grid.Column="3" Click="Click_savedColor"/>

</Grid>
```

C# Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ColorSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        Color color = Color.FromRgb((byte)slColorR.Value, (byte)slColorG.Value, (byte)slColorB.Value);
        compColor.Background = new SolidColorBrush(color);
    }

    void Click_compColor(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        savedColor.Background = compColor.Background;
    }

    void Click_savedColor(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        bool bools = Convert.ToBoolean(savedColor.Background);
        byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(bools);

        slColorR.Value = Convert.ToDouble(bytes[0]);
        slColorG.Value = Convert.ToDouble(bytes[1]);
        slColorB.Value = Convert.ToDouble(bytes[2]);

        compColor.Background = savedColor.Background;
    }
}
```

Below is an image of the program: First box contains color sliders; second box contains color of color sliders; third box contains saved color from second box.

[image: Image of program]

Comment: What are you trying to do converting `Brush` to `bool`  `bool bools = Convert.ToBoolean(savedColor.Background);` ???

Comment: The color value you want to be saving is not some brush; a brush can represent all kinds of things that have many colors. You want the Color.FromRGB() value you got in ColorSlider_ValueChanged. Just save it in a private field.

Comment: I realize now I wasn't as clear as I thought I was.

I am using the Slider values, 0-255, to represent each respective color spectrum and then applying those values to

Color color = Color.FromRgb((byte)slColorR.Value, (byte)slColorG.Value, (byte)slColorB.Value);

which then I apply and save that color.

I want to load the color that was saved and then break it down into it's respective rgb values and place those values back into the rgb sliders.

I would just save the slider values but I receive errors that I can't do that outside of the private void ColorSlider_ValueChanged class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not understanding how you trying to save you color. But there is `Color` property in `SolidColorBrush`, so you can take all color components from that:

```
var red = savedColor.Background.Color.R;
var green = savedColor.Background.Color.G;
var blue = savedColor.Background.Color.B;
```

Comment: In regards to .Color: 

'Brush' does not contain definition for 'Color' and no extension method 'Color' accepting a first argument of the type 'Brush' could be found (are you missing a directive or assembly reference?)

Comment: @Planet_Earth `Brush` has no, `SolidColorBrush` has one. I guess you had to `var red = ((SolidColorBrush)savedColor.Background).Color.R;

Comment: This is relatively new to me. Are you suggesting that I save as SolidColorBrush, or try to call my color as a SolidColorBrush?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Properties, by implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface, and binding Properties to corresponding value sliders. For example:

```
private int _GreenValue;
private int _RedValue;
private int _BlueValue;
private Color _BackGroundColor;


public int GreenValue
{
    get { return _GreenValue; }
    set
    {
        _GreenValue = value;
        _BackGroundColor = Color.FromArgb(_RedValue, _GreenValue, _BlueValue);
    }
}
public int MyProperty
{
    get { return _RedValue; }
    set
    {
        _RedValue = value;
        _BackGroundColor = Color.FromArgb(_RedValue, _GreenValue, _BlueValue);
    }
}
public int BlueValue
{
    get { return _BlueValue; }
    set
    {
        _BlueValue = value;
        _BackGroundColor = Color.FromArgb(_RedValue, _GreenValue, _BlueValue);
    }
}

public Color BackGroundColor
{
    get { return _BackGroundColor; }
}
```

Where `BackGroundColor` is a read-only field which will change any of the associated integer value changed.